# Grunt plugin grunt-exec v2.0.0 doesn't execute a simple command while v1.0.1 does

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-exec

I was using grunt-exec v1.0.1 with this configuration in `Gruntfile.js`:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    exec: {
        tsc: {
            cmd: "tsc"
        }
    },
    ...
}

...

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

grunt.registerTask('debug', [
    ...
    'exec:tsc',
    ...
]);
```

Then running `grunt debug` in console `tsc` is executed correctly.

In another project with similar configuration it's installed the last version of
 `grunt-exec`(v.2.0.0) and running `grunt-debug` the next error is returned:

```
Running "exec:tsc" (exec) task
>> Failed with: Error: spawn tsc ENOENT
Warning: Task "exec:tsc" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

With `-verbose` option it returns:

```
Running "exec:tsc" (exec) task
Verifying property exec.tsc exists in config...OK
File: [no files]

tsc
buffer   : disabled
timeout  : infinite
killSig  : SIGTERM
shell    : true
command  : tsc
args     : []
stdio    : [ignore,pipe,pipe]
cwd      : D:\Pruebas\Angular 2\ATemplate
exitcodes: 0
pid     : undefined
>> Failed with: Error: spawn tsc ENOENT
Warning: Task "exec:tsc" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I know I can have it working using v1.0.1 of grunt-exec but I want to know how must I do it with v2.0.0. The [project documentation in github](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) has not given me a clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `grunt-exec` version v2.0.0 uses some ECMAScript features that are not supported in older versions of node.

The first one i saw was:

`Symbol.match, String.prototype.endsWith` that is not supported in node < v6.10.2
See here: http://node.green/

Upgrade your node version to fix this issue.